# Creating a smooth transition for hidden elements with CSS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a list that expands when you click on it, and make it smooth using `transition 1s all`.  However there is hidden part in the list, that I want to expand when the user clicks on the item.  But i cannot get it to expand smoothly, it just seems to toggle it on/off.

[See the JSFiddle for the code.](https://jsfiddle.net/87rxc9hk/)

Could anyone help?

Edit: I want it to toggle in height (much like BootStrap's `collapse` class). Not toggle the `display` property.

If you bothered to look at the code, *Praveen*, you would have seen that.

Comment: You can't use `auto` for transitions. There are work arounds though. You can keep `height: auto` on all the time, and transition `max-height: 0px` to `max-height: 30px` or whatever is reasonable. May not be perfect, but it'll work.
https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: added the duplicate for the height ... if you want more I can add, all of them exists